Wrong concept in rolling question
A solid sphere of radius R is placed on smooth horizontal surface. A
horizontal force F is applied at height h from the lowest point. For
the maximum acceleration of centre of mass, which is correct?

h=r
h=2R
h=0
no relation between h and R (NEET 2002)

Available solutions indicate option 4, but this directly contradicts the information here since rolling will take up energy and hence reduce the acceleration.
Note: I am not interested in the answer to a homework/exam question. I am interested in the concept of whether an object on a horizontal smooth surface will roll. And while I cannot contact the examiners, I do want to understand the concept correctly.

You are misunderstanding the solutions. Both are in agreement. The centre of mass moves as if the rotation part is ignored and ignorable, because the horizontal surface is smooth. The rotation coming from the initial force pushing on it, induces different amounts of rotation, and it is not clear that there would be the same amount of rotational KE. The linear KE will be the same.

But the solution says there will be no rolling. Isn't that part of it wrong, even if the final answer is correct?

The rolling is not due to the friction with the ground. It is in that sense that it is ok. Yes, the same force produces the same linear momentum, i.e. same linear KE, but different angular KE.

There is one horizontal force, $F$, acting on the sphere.

Applying two equal magnitude, $F$, and opposite direction to each other forces, $F_1$ and $F_2$, at the centre of mass $C$ results in a force $F_2$ acting at the centre of mass of the sphere which produces a translational acceleration, $a$ of the centre of mass $(F=m\,a)$, and a couple $F\,h$ which produces an angular acceleration, $\alpha$, about the centre of mass $F\,h= I_{\rm com}\alpha$.
So the linear acceleration is independent of the position the force $F$ is applied, Option $D$, and there will be an angular acceleration of the sphere unless $h=0$.

This very diagram is why earlier textbooks on mechanics would consider the "couple" concept; that earlier textbooks cover this and yet not explain to students why they wanted to cover this topic, is why such an important and obviously useful concept later ended up taken out of textbooks, because the students who later turned into professors on their own right, did not understand why their teachers taught them the concept. It is a farce. It takes so little effort to just explain why we introduce concepts...

Appendix 20A Chasles’s Theorem: Rotation and Translation of a Rigid Body - page 20

So the same force produces a constant linear acceleration and a varying angular acceleration? I am trying to undertand why that is not a violation of the principle of conservation of energy.

@Starlight That is a good question. In terms of work done note that the force will move further than the centre of mass when the line of action of the force is not through the centre of mass. So more work is done when off centre which is where the increase in rotational kinetic energy comes from.
